# How to stop consumers

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I made a simple Jms project with 2 java files names are `MessageSender.java,MessageConsumer.java`.one for sending messages to `Activemq:Queue` and another for consuming messages from `Activemq:Queue`.Deployed this project in `Apache Tomcat`.following code was consumer code.

```
 ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://localhost:61617?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1"); 
 Connection connection=connectionFactory.createConnection(); 
 final Session session=connection.createSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE); 
 Queue queue=session.createQueue("ThermalMap"); 
 javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer=session.createConsumer(queue); 
 //anonymous class 
  MessageListener listener = new MessageListener() { 
            @Override 
            public void onMessage(Message msg) { 
             // My business code 
            } 
};
```

Later If I want to change consumer code,I don't want to stop `Tomcat`because If I stop `Tomcat` entire `jms project` should not work. So clients can't able to sent messages to `Activemq:Queue`.So I don't want to follow this way.

I am thinking, If I stop consumers through Activemq console page.I don't need to stop `Tomcat` So clients can able to send messages normally.For this I check `AMQ console page`,I didn't seen any consumers.

1. Is it correct way to do this.
2. If it is correct way, How can I do this.

can anyone suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Call the [.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#close%28%29) method on your MessageConsumer.

Comment: If I use `.close()` in my `Messageconsumer`it will close after processing 1 messages.If I want to modify any consumer code then only I want to stop consumer.

Comment: I modified my question. can you check this.

Comment: @Hanumath You don't need to close() in your message consumer, you can close() it elsewhere.

Comment: can I close consumer from `Activemq` web console page. If it was not possible. Where will I close.

Comment: @Hanumath the web console will close the broker end of the connection. You'll need to close your end, and possibly re establish the connection. You need to create some interface for doing so, e.g. a web page/servlet or similar.